# How to implement MVVM on an application that allows user to draw on canvas?

Tags: mvvm, architecture

The application allows the user to draw on a canvas, these are some of the things they can draw:

1. Draw line: User starts by clicking a point on the canvas to mark the start point, then drag and release the mouse to mark the end point.
2. Draw rectangle: User starts by clicking a point on the canvas to mark the first corner of the rectangle, then drag and release the mouse to mark the opposite corner.
3. Draw circle: User starts by clicking a point on the canvas to mark the start of the radius (i.e. this is the center of circle), then drag and release the mouse to mark the end of the radius of the circle.

These require interaction using the mouse, so it is impossible to use Command. How would the View tell the ViewModel all the mouse events and the mouse coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create ViewModel for screen and objects that you want to create, and some custom controls for drawing .

Lots of use full sample in internet

Some links :

[Scribble-WPF-InkCanvas-Application-Using-PRISM-MVVM](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617868/Scribble-WPF-InkCanvas-Application-Using-PRISM-MVV)

[Adventures-into-Ink-API-using-WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19102/Adventures-into-Ink-API-using-WPF)

[MVVM-Diagram-Designer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/484616/MVVM-Diagram-Designer)

[SimpleEditor](https://github.com/SVoyt/SimpleEditor)

Answer (score 0):

> These require interaction using the mouse, so it is impossible to use
>   Command. How would the View tell the ViewModel all the mouse events
>   and the mouse coordinates?

You can use [`EventToCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) to bind an event to a command and use a command parameter and a [converter](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/) to pass and convert `MouseEventArgs` to an object which will contain all the necessary data to implement your drawing logic.

Here is a simple example how to do this in MvvmLight to demonstrate how to track and bind `ViewModel` properties to mouse position and left mouse button state.

First of all you obviously define `ViewModel` properties which will hold mouse position and state:

```
private double _posX = 0;
public double PosX
{
    // ...
}

private double _posY = 0;
public double PosY
{
    // ...
}

private bool _isClicked = false;
public bool IsClicked
{
    // ...
}
```

The next step is to create a converter which will convert `MouseEventArgs` to an object which will then be used in your `ViewModel` to hold and interpret the mouse event data. In this example we will store it in a custom `MouseData` object:

```
public class MouseData
{
    public double PosX { get; set; }
    public double PosY { get; set; }
    public bool IsClicked { get; set; }
}

public class MouseEventArgsConverter : IEventArgsConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
    {
        var args = (MouseEventArgs)value;
        var element = (FrameworkElement)parameter;
        var point = args.GetPosition(element);

        var mouseData = new MouseData();
        mouseData.PosX = point.X;
        mouseData.PosY = point.Y;
        mouseData.IsClicked = args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed;

        return mouseData;
    }
}
```

Then you define a command which accepts a converted parameter and implements your drawing logic:

```
public ICommand MouseMoveCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}
private void MouseMoveCommandExecute(MouseData e)
{
    PosX = e.PosX;
    PosY = e.PosY;
    IsClicked = e.IsClicked;

    // draw lines, rectangles, circles, ecc. here
}
```

Finally in your XAML you bind `Canvas` `MouseMove` event to a newly created command and specify the converter which has to be used to convert event arg:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"

...

<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="LightGray">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MouseEventArgsConverter x:Key="MouseEventArgsConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseMoveCommand}"
                                EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource MouseEventArgsConverter}"
                                EventArgsConverterParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas}"
                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: If you're handling mouse data in the VM, you're not MVVMing. Not a horrible thing, as the pattern serves us, but you're cramming UI logic down into the vm. better to handle the initial creation logic in the codebehind and, once shape and location data is confirmed, pass that into the VM so a shape model can be created and placed in the shapes OC.

Comment: @Will That's exactly the dilemma I'm facing. Mouse event is pretty much a GUI thing, but in the application, it seems to me how the canvas reacts to mouse event is also a *business logic*. For example, it may be perceived that using single clicks can cause many accidental creation of small shapes, so we would want to change the start to doubleclicks.

Comment: Nah, that's still UI logic. Again, the pattern exists to serve us, not the other way around, so don't get hung up too much about finding the line dogmatically. Handling mouse clicks and interpreting user intent is all UI stuff. Notably, it's easiest to handle correctly at that level. So handle it there! You can translate intent into ICommand executions and property setters later.